# Find an replace text from unstructured csv

Tags: regex, batch-file, csv, replace, cmd

I have a log file with (¬ deliminator).

```
073957.744 : Send:[8=FIX.4.4¬9=724¬35=AE¬49=FAUAT¬56=CALUAT¬34=82¬55=0000 AA BBC¬48=0000 AA BBC¬22=100¬38=17000.000000¬9998=Equity¬9999=CFD¬]
080655.776 : Send:[8=FIX.4.4¬9=631¬35=AE¬49=FAUAT¬56=CALUAT¬34=136¬55=NOVN VX CFD¬48=NOVN VX CFD¬22=100¬38=7500.000000¬]
081249.475 : Send:[8=FIX.4.4¬9=620¬35=AE¬49=FAUAT¬56=CALUAT¬34=148¬55=NOK1V FH CFD¬48=NOK1V FH CFD¬22=100¬38=50000.000000¬9896=False¬9893=1¬]
081806.623 : Send:[8=FIX.4.4¬9=583¬35=AE¬49=FAUAT¬56=CALUAT¬34=159¬55=IX17186393-0¬48=IX17186393-0¬22=110¬38=10.000000¬60=20131216-08:09:02¬64=20131219¬552=1¬54=1¬]
```

I am using the following code to convert the file in csv and remove the first 7 columns

```
@echo off

rem fetch only the required messages from log file
findstr /r /i Send:\[.*35=AE.* %cd%\FixProvider_MsgLog_20131216_1.log > %cd%\FilteredFIXMessages.log

rem ensure the older temp file is not present
if exist %cd%\FIXTemp1.tmp del %cd%\FIXTemp1.tmp

rem convert the FilteredFIXMessages.log into csv and store it in temp1 file and strip temp1 file for the first 6 columns as they are not required for data matching
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-6* delims=¬" %%a in (%cd%\FilteredFIXMessages.log) do set data=%%h & echo !data:=¬,! >> %cd%\FIXTemp1.tmp

exit /b
```

This gives me the following CSV

```
55=0000 AA BBC,48=0000 AA BBC,22=100,38=17000.000000,9998=Equity,9999=CFD,]  
55=NOVN VX CFD,48=NOVN VX CFD,22=100,38=7500.000000,]  
55=NOK1V FH CFD,48=NOK1V FH CFD,22=100,38=50000.000000,9896=False,9893=1,]  
55=IX17186393-0,48=IX17186393-0,22=110,38=10.000000,60=20131216-08:09:02,64=20131219,552=1,54=1,]
```

As you can see that this is not a structured csv (no fixed columns and the column order too may vary), I want to strip out

1. Columns like 55=* or any column(s) which I want (the data may be of variable length, but the column markers are static like 55= etc)
2. The last column `,]` (empty col)

I can easily strip this using VBS, but since I am using a batch script, I would like to continue with it and not install any other tool. Please help.

Comment: I was looking at docs of `for`. So token 7 (%h) gets each delimeted segment past 6 to the end? I looked at help, there is no command like `printf` to format the string. You could probably write your own exe to simulate printf, returning a padded string, but don't know if you could call it from the do body. Even if you could, you would have to make 2 passes on the file, one to find out max columns and width, one to format the data. But, why does this csv needs to be of fixed structure?

Comment: @sln - The CSV doesn't need to be of fixed structure and hence the issue of variable length text find and replace. And as i mentioned, i can easily do this using VBS (as i am more comfortable in it), but would like to do it in one single BAT file.

Comment: The biggest problem you face is getting rid of that `=` sign. You just can't easily do it in batch. I'd just use a hybrid vbs/batch script if you want it all in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: Parenthesise a statement-group with redirector sends all echoed text to file
(
 REM This is simply using your regex to feed the lines to FOR
 REM Tokenised - first 5 tokens are skipped, #6 to %%a, remainder of line to %%b
 FOR /f "tokens=6* delims=¬" %%a IN ('findstr /r /i "Send:\[.*35=AE.*" q21191380.txt') DO (
  REM set LINE to token7+(with delimiters) and clear NEWLINE
  SET line=%%b
  SET "newline="
  CALL :process
 )
)>newfile.txt
TYPE newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:process
:: Grab the first token in LINE to %%s, part after delimiter to %%t
:: Then set FIELD to "line=nexttoken" and LINE to remaining text
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=¬" %%s IN ('set line') DO SET "field=%%s"&SET "line=%%t"
:: Remove the leading "line=" from LINE (5 characters)
SET "field=%field:~5%"
:: Vanilla FOR for quoted strings (which bypasses the special status of "=")
:: Set a work variable=FIELD and set string=(element from list - quotes)
FOR %%e IN ("55=" "]") DO SET "work=%field%"&SET "string=%%~e"&CALL :elim
:: ELIM will either clear FIELD or leave it untouched - build & separate
IF DEFINED field SET "newline=%newline%,%field%"
:: If there's any more left in LINE, repeat the process until LINE is empty
IF DEFINED line GOTO process
:: NEWLINE will start with a comma, so ECHO it minus the first character
IF DEFINED newline ECHO %newline:~1%
GOTO :eof

:elim
:: Does the first character of WORK = first of STRING?
IF NOT "%string:~0,1%"=="%work:~0,1%" GOTO :EOF
:: Yes - lop off the first character of both
SET "string=%string:~1%"
SET "work=%work:~1%"
:: If both are still defined, repeat
IF DEFINED string IF DEFINED work GOTO elim
:: If there's anything left to match in STRING, we've found where STRING and WORK differ,
IF DEFINED string GOTO :EOF
:: STRING has been completely matched, so clear FIELD to drop it from output
SET "field="
GOTO :eof
```

Now there was an interesting exercise!

I've changed the names of the files to suit my system, but otherwise, should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for this. One request - Can you comment your code so that its easier for me to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks again. I have tried it with different combinations of columns and it is working absolutely fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hybrid script that will do it.

```
::Find and Replace
::Matt Williamson 
::5/30/2013

@echo off
setlocal

call :FindReplace "55=" "" in.txt
call :FindReplace ",]" "" in.txt

exit /b 

:FindReplace <findstr> <replstr> <file>
set tmp="%temp%\tmp.txt"
If not exist %temp%\_.vbs call :MakeReplace
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%3" /s /b /a-d /on') do (
  for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`Findstr /mic:"%~1" "%%a"`) do (
    echo(&Echo Replacing "%~1" with "%~2" in file %%~nxa
    <%%a cscript //nologo %temp%\_.vbs "%~1" "%~2">%tmp%
    if exist %tmp% move /Y %tmp% "%%~dpnxa">nul
  )
)
del %temp%\_.vbs
exit /b

:MakeReplace
>%temp%\_.vbs echo with Wscript
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo set args=.arguments
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo .StdOut.Write _
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo Replace(.StdIn.ReadAll,args(0),args(1),1,-1,1)
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo end with
```

Comment: Although I wanted a batch only solution, but yours is also a neat way to do it.